# Sharing a connection object across actors

Tags: java, akka, state

I am trying to request an external webservice from my actor system. When a new request comes in I perform actions A, B, C on the webService

```
A: Create http connection and Get Auth Token
B: Create http connection and Use A's token Access API  and get result
C: Create http connection and Use A and B's result  to access API and get result
```

For these I am planning to have actors A , B and C to separate the logic and communicate using `Patterns.ask()` ..

Note that I am creating an HTTP connection for every request thats going to the server, is there a way to pass the same connection to instances of actor's A , b and C?

Comment: probably the same way you get A's token from a to b.

Comment: So have one actor that creates an Http connection and have it pass to the other actors using Patterns.ask?

Comment: Instead of asking for just a token you could ask for a container holding a token and a connection. Or something similar that encapsulates the progress so far. Or has a reference to the required things.

Comment: So every time an instance of actor is created it will ask for this 'session' wont that create too many sessions? I am confused

Comment: A opens a http connection & sends it together with token to B. B does it's thing and sends connection, token and its result to C. That would be 1 connection opened per overall request. -  In case you're even able to reuse http connections that easily because I've never seen a way to pass an open http connection around. You might be better off not worrying about connections at all by using a connection pooling capable implementation like https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Connections#connections - besides that, I'm not sure it's a great use of actors at all because this is all sequential?

Comment: Hmm I might have framed it incorrectly, A definitely needs to complete before B or C can perform tasks,  B and C are independent of each other but need a token and an http connection. If not actors , do you think the three tasks should be performed by a single actor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127926/discussion-between-user-mda-and-zapl).